# How to run a function in the background as well as in the foreground Android Studio(JAVA)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a function I need to run this function in background as Well as in foreground. this function read the Value from BLE server. When I click on button it gave me the updated value but I don't want to get the value from click. I want it run everytime and update the value in text field.

```
    public void readData(){
        if(manager.getConnectedDevices().size()<=0){
            Toast.makeText(ModeFragment.this.getActivity(),"No connected devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        device1 = manager.getConnectedDevices().get(0);
        Map<String , String> reciveData =  getSpecificServiceInfo(device1 , CHARACTERISTIC_READABLE);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : reciveData.entrySet()){
            manager.read(device1, e.getKey(), e.getValue(), new BleReadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onRead(byte[] data, BleDevice device) {
                    Toast.makeText(ModeFragment.this.getActivity(), "Read success!   data:  " + new String(data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    String str = data.toString();
//                    List<String> data1 = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
                    textView.setText(new String(data));
                    intent.putExtra("data" , new String(data));

                    }

                @Override
                public void onFail(int failCode, String info, BleDevice device) {
//                    Toast.makeText(ModeFragment.this.getActivity(), "Read fail!   data:  " + info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Oncreate Meathod:

```
btnread.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        readData();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a handler and a runnable. The runnable will take care of the background work and then the handler will post it to the UI thread.

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {....} // This is the work to do on the background
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

You can check this part of the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Does your runnable get a variable from your onCreate? Otherwise you can just add the mainHandler.post(myRunnable); in the onCreate method; The handler and the runnable are variables.

Comment: the values are coming from a server BLE. I just want to run this in the background and foreground. and it update the textVIew everytime

Comment: I tried this it gave an error. 
error: incompatible types: <anonymous BleReadCallback> cannot be converted to Runnable
                      mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);